# Suggestion for tools/libraries for multi-output boolean circuit minimization?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, np-hard, circuits

I am interested in the following problem

> Input: A boolean function F with n boolean inputs and m boolean outputs.
>
> Output: A circuit C implementing F such that C has as few gates as possible.

The function F could either be given as a boolean truth table, or more likely, another circuit D.

I realize that this is a prototypical $\Sigma^P_2$ problem. However, I suppose that since this problem is important in practice, there are tools which would do this via some heuristics and/or relaxing some efficiency/correctness guarantees.

What are some tools/libraries and/or widely used algorithms for this?

For example, one tool I found is [PyEDA](https://github.com/cjdrake/pyeda) which seems to be based on the [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer) algorithm

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/11022/5038, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48694/5038

Comment: @D.W. while I can see that these techniques could be employed to this problem in some way, I am looking for libraries/tools dedicated to the logic optimization problem

Comment: Do you have any examples of typical values of $n,m$, and typical circuit size for $C$?

Comment: @D.W. I imagine m is between 10-20 bits, and n is m + 8